# React Props with same type/ value and different types

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I have a following Text filed which has been created through Material-ui.

```
 <TextField
                  error = {this.props.projectNameErrorStatus}
                  required = {this.props.projectNameRequiredStatus}
                  className={classes.textField}
                  margin="normal"
                  id="projectName"
                  name="projectName"

                />
```

However, I have 4 different TextFields which I am going to set error props to them with different name that take state of parent container. this issue will force me to have 8 different props and state's names. this will make my code larger and less readable.
For example I have to initiate state:

```
state = {
projectNameErrorStatus :true,
NameErrorStatus :true,
FamilyErrorStatus :true,
EmailErrorStatus :true,
projectNameRequiredStatus: true,
NameRequiredStatus: true,
FamilyRequiredStatus: true,
EmailRequiredStatus: true,

}

state = {this.state}
```

and then pass them as props to child component. After that I should use all them as props in.

```
let {

state = {
projectNameErrorStatus,
NameErrorStatus,
FamilyErrorStatus,
EmailErrorStatus,
projectNameRequiredStatus,
NameRequiredStatus,
FamilyRequiredStatus,
EmailRequiredStatus

} = this.props.state
```

Can I have these props and state in a more cleaner and efficien way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it in two Components and use json objects:

```
    import React from 'react';


class customTextfield extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <TextField
                error={this.props.ErrorStatus}
                required={this.props.RequiredStatus}
                className={classes.textField}
                margin="normal"
                id={this.props.Name}
                name={this.props.Name} 
                label={this.props.Label} />
        );
    }

}

class parentContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            ErrorStatus = {
                Name: true,
                Email: false,
                Project: false,
                Family: false
            },
            RequiredStatus = {
                Name: true,
                Email: true,
                Project: true,
                Family: false
            },
            listOfTextFields =["Name", "Email", "Project", "Family"]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.listOfTextFields.map(field => <customTextfield Name={field} Label={field} ErrorStatus={this.state.ErrorStatus[field]} RequiredStatus={this.state.RequiredStatus[field]} />)
    };
}
```

Comment: What about label if I am going to add? labels are not the same

Comment: Labels are not same as fields' values. For example labels = ['GivenName','EmailAddress','ProjectName','FamilyName']. I am wondering if I can use 2d array which contains fileds and labels next to eachother like var Sample2DArray = [[Name,GivenName],[Family,FamilyName],[Project,ProjectName],[email,EmailAddres]]

Comment: Sure you cam fill the Label property with everything you want. Instead if 2d arrays i would suggest json objects